# In-editor spell checking for PHP, HTML files

Tags: php, html, xhtml, spell-checking, komodoedit

I always have trouble spell checking websites via the editor because they always pick up the code as well and complain about things like `stylesheet` or `css` for example.

Is there any way I can spell check all my files without using an online tool to just check the content? Dynamic text also needs to be checked.

My editor is `Komodo Edit` FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this editor it is easy to use .. less size.. it has spell checker and lot of thing..

http://www.sublimetext.com/

download a editor..

Comment: No different than Komodo, the spell check complains about code as well.

Comment: you want editor or.. any extention will be ok for you.. or something like net bean is ok..

Comment: I want an editor or anything for that matter where the spell checking doesn't check the code for spelling.